Mathematica code To extract tabulated data after conversion from pdf to text
I've written the following code in Mathematica to extract the data I need from invoices which are in pdf format but can vary in terms of layout and terminology:
(*Prepare Training Data*)
trainingDataItemDesc = {
  "Description" -> "SimilarString", "DESCRIPTION" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Product Name" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Product Details" -> "SimilarString", "Products" -> "SimilarString",
   "Product" -> "SimilarString", "Details" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Desc" -> "SimilarString", "ITEM" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Product Description" -> "SimilarString", "" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Item Description" -> "SimilarString", "ITEMS" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Description of Goods Sold" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Part Number/Description" -> "SimilarString", 
  "PRODUCT NAME" -> "SimilarString", 
  "PRODUCT DETAILS" -> "SimilarString", "PRODUCTS" -> "SimilarString",
   "PRODUCT" -> "SimilarString", "DETAILS" -> "SimilarString", 
  "DESC" -> "SimilarString", "PRODUCT DESCRIPTION" -> "SimilarString",
   "ITEM DESCRIPTION" -> "SimilarString", 
  "DESCRIPTION OF GOODS SOLD" -> "SimilarString", 
  "PART NUMBER/DESCRIPTION" -> "SimilarString", 
  "description" -> "SimilarString", "product name" -> "SimilarString",
   "product details" -> "SimilarString", 
  "products" -> "SimilarString", "product" -> "SimilarString", 
  "details" -> "SimilarString", "desc" -> "SimilarString", 
  "item" -> "SimilarString", "product description" -> "SimilarString",
   "item description" -> "SimilarString", "items" -> "SimilarString", 
  "description of goods sold" -> "SimilarString", 
  "part number/description" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Description:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "DESCRIPTION:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Product Name:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Product Details:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Products:" -> "SimilarString", "Product:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Details:" -> "SimilarString", "Desc:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "ITEM:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Product Description:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Item Description:" -> "SimilarString", "ITEMS:" -> "SimilarString",
   "Description of Goods Sold:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Part Number/Description:" -> "SimilarString",
  "Total" -> "NotSimilar", "TOTAL REMITTANCE:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "[GBP] TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", "Total:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Grand Total:" -> "NotSimilar", "Invoice total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total VAT" -> "NotSimilar", "Total Paid" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Amount Due:" -> "NotSimilar", "AMOUNT (USD)" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Order Total" -> "NotSimilar", "" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Invoice Total:" -> "NotSimilar", "Gross Total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Net Price (per unit)" -> "NotSimilar", "TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total paid" -> "NotSimilar", "Invoice Total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "TOTAL INC. VAT:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total Amount Due" -> "NotSimilar", "TOTAL:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "GRAND TOTAL:" -> "NotSimilar", "INVOICE TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "TOTAL VAT" -> "NotSimilar", "TOTAL PAID" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "AMOUNT DUE:" -> "NotSimilar", "ORDER TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "INVOICE TOTAL:" -> "NotSimilar", "GROSS TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "NET PRICE (PER UNIT)" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "TOTAL AMOUNT DUE" -> "NotSimilar", "total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total remittance:" -> "NotSimilar", "[gbp] total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total:" -> "NotSimilar", "grand total:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "invoice total" -> "NotSimilar", "total vat" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total paid" -> "NotSimilar", "amount due:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "amount (usd)" -> "NotSimilar", "order total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "invoice total:" -> "NotSimilar", "gross total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "net price (per unit)" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total inc. vat:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total amount due" -> "NotSimilar", "[GBP] TOTAL:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Invoice total:" -> "NotSimilar", "Total VAT:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total Paid:" -> "NotSimilar", "AMOUNT (USD):" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Order Total:" -> "NotSimilar", "Gross Total:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Net Price (per unit):" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total paid:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total Amount Due:" -> "NotSimilar"}; trainingDataSubtot = {
  "Subtotal" -> "SimilarString", "Nett Total:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "COMPONENT TOTAL" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Sub-Total:" -> "SimilarString", "Sub Total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Subtotal:" -> "SimilarString", "" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Total goods ex VAT" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Sub-Total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Net value of goods" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Total Net Amount" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Net Total:" -> "SimilarString", "Sub-total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Goods Value" -> "SimilarString", "Products" -> "SimilarString", 
  "SUB-TOTAL:" -> "SimilarString", "Net Amount" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Nett Total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Total Nett Goods" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Invoice Total" -> "SimilarString", "SUBTOTAL" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Net total" -> "SimilarString", "NETT TOTAL:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "SUB TOTAL" -> "SimilarString", "SUBTOTAL:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "TOTAL GOODS EX VAT" -> "SimilarString", 
  "SUB-TOTAL" -> "SimilarString", 
  "NET VALUE OF GOODS" -> "SimilarString", 
  "TOTAL NET AMOUNT" -> "SimilarString", 
  "NET TOTAL:" -> "SimilarString", "GOODS VALUE" -> "SimilarString", 
  "PRODUCTS" -> "SimilarString", "NET AMOUNT" -> "SimilarString", 
  "NETT TOTAL" -> "SimilarString", 
  "TOTAL NETT GOODS" -> "SimilarString", 
  "INVOICE TOTAL" -> "SimilarString", "NET TOTAL" -> "SimilarString", 
  "subtotal" -> "SimilarString", "nett total:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "component total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "sub-total:" -> "SimilarString", "sub total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "subtotal:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "total goods ex vat" -> "SimilarString", 
  "sub-total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "net value of goods" -> "SimilarString", 
  "total net amount" -> "SimilarString", 
  "net total:" -> "SimilarString", "goods value" -> "SimilarString", 
  "products" -> "SimilarString", "net amount" -> "SimilarString", 
  "nett total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "total nett goods" -> "SimilarString", 
  "invoice total" -> "SimilarString", "net total" -> "SimilarString", 
  "COMPONENT TOTAL:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Sub Total:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Total goods ex VAT:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Net value of goods:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Total Net Amount:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Sub-total:" -> "SimilarString", "Goods Value:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Products:" -> "SimilarString", "Net Amount:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Total Nett Goods:" -> "SimilarString", 
  "Invoice Total:" -> "SimilarString", "Net total:" -> "SimilarString",
  "Total" -> "NotSimilar", "TOTAL REMITTANCE:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "[GBP] TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", "Total:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Grand Total:" -> "NotSimilar", "Invoice total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total VAT" -> "NotSimilar", "Total Paid" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Amount Due:" -> "NotSimilar", "AMOUNT (USD)" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Order Total" -> "NotSimilar", "" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Invoice Total:" -> "NotSimilar", "Gross Total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Net Price (per unit)" -> "NotSimilar", "TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total paid" -> "NotSimilar", "Invoice Total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "TOTAL INC. VAT:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total Amount Due" -> "NotSimilar", "TOTAL:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "GRAND TOTAL:" -> "NotSimilar", "INVOICE TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "TOTAL VAT" -> "NotSimilar", "TOTAL PAID" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "AMOUNT DUE:" -> "NotSimilar", "ORDER TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "INVOICE TOTAL:" -> "NotSimilar", "GROSS TOTAL" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "NET PRICE (PER UNIT)" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "TOTAL AMOUNT DUE" -> "NotSimilar", "total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total remittance:" -> "NotSimilar", "[gbp] total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total:" -> "NotSimilar", "grand total:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "invoice total" -> "NotSimilar", "total vat" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total paid" -> "NotSimilar", "amount due:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "amount (usd)" -> "NotSimilar", "order total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "invoice total:" -> "NotSimilar", "gross total" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "net price (per unit)" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total inc. vat:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "total amount due" -> "NotSimilar", "[GBP] TOTAL:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Invoice total:" -> "NotSimilar", "Total VAT:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total Paid:" -> "NotSimilar", "AMOUNT (USD):" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Order Total:" -> "NotSimilar", "Gross Total:" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Net Price (per unit):" -> "NotSimilar", 
  "Total paid:" -> "NotSimilar", "Total Amount Due:" -> "NotSimilar"};

(*Train a Machine Learning Classifier*)
modelItemDesc = Classify[trainingDataItemDesc];
modelSubtot = Classify[trainingDataSubtot];

(*Set Up the Word COM Interface*)
extractTextFromPDFUsingPDFtoText[pdfPath_String] := 
 Module[{outputPath, result}, 
  outputPath = 
   FileNameJoin[{DirectoryName[pdfPath], 
     FileBaseName[pdfPath] <> ".txt"}];
  RunProcess[{"C:\\Poppler\\Library\\bin\\pdftotext.exe", "-layout", 
    pdfPath, outputPath}];
  result = Import[outputPath, "Text"];
  If[result === "", extractTextWithOCR[pdfPath], result]]

(*Determine If OCR Is Required*)
requiresOCR[text_String] := 
 StringLength[text] < 50 || 
  StringMatchQ[text, RegularExpression["[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"], 
   IgnoreCase -> True]

(*OCR Extraction Function*)
extractTextWithOCR[filename_String] := Module[{pages, ocrText},
  (*Try to import the PDF as individual images*)
  pages = Import[filename, {"PDF", "Pages"}];
  (*If import fails,return a failure message*)
  If[pages === $Failed, Return["$Failed"]];
  (*Apply OCR to each page*)ocrText = TextRecognize /@ pages;
  (*Combine the recognized text from all pages*)StringJoin[ocrText]]

(*Combined Text Extraction Function*)
extractTextFromPDF[filename_String] := 
 Module[{text},(*First,try to extract text using Microsoft Word*)
  Print[filename];
  text = Quiet[Check[extractTextFromPDFUsingPDFtoText[filename], ""]];
  
  (*If the extracted text is empty or looks like gibberish,apply OCR*)

  
  If[requiresOCR[text], Print["Requires OCR"];
   text = extractTextWithOCR[filename]];
  text]

(*Search through all subfolders in a folder and extract all.pdf \
filenames*)
getAllPDFs[folder_String] := FileNames["*.pdf", folder, Infinity];

(*Specify the training and main folders where the PDFs are located*)
mainFolder = 
  "Z:\\Shared\\03 - Operations\\06 - Supply Chain\\Invoice Data \
Extraction\\Example Invoices";

Print["Getting a list of all PDF files in the folder and its \
subfolders..."];
(*Get a list of all PDF files in the folder and its subfolders*)
pdfFiles = getAllPDFs[mainFolder];

(*Initialize a list to store the first entries in \
extractedNumbersSubtot for each file*)
firstEntriesItemDesc = {};
firstEntriesSubtot = {};

(*Process each file in the folder*)
Do[
  
  (*Load the file content*)
  invoiceText = extractTextFromPDF[pdfFiles[[i]]];
  
  (*Find positionsSubtot of phrases in the file content that match \
similar strings*)
  allPositionsItemDesc = {};
  allPositionsSubtot = {};
  
  Do[
   (*Find positionsItemDesc of the current phrase in the file content*)

   
   positionsItemDesc = StringPosition[invoiceText, phrase];
   
   (*Classify the phrase if it's found in the text*)
   If[Length[positionsItemDesc] > 0 && 
     modelItemDesc[phrase] === "SimilarString",
    (*Add all positionsItemDesc of this phrase to the list*)
    allPositionsItemDesc = 
     Join[allPositionsItemDesc, positionsItemDesc]
    ],
   {phrase, Keys[trainingDataItemDesc]}
   ];
  
  Do[
   (*Find positionsSubtot of the current phrase in the file content*)

   
   positionsSubtot = StringPosition[invoiceText, phrase];
   
   (*Classify the phrase if it's found in the text*)
   If[Length[positionsSubtot] > 0 && 
     modelSubtot[phrase] === "SimilarString",
    (*Add all positionsSubtot of this phrase to the list*)
    allPositionsSubtot = Join[allPositionsSubtot, positionsSubtot]
    ],
   {phrase, Keys[trainingDataSubtot]}
   ];
  
  (*Extract Numbers Next to Similar Strings*)
  allItemDescriptions = {};
  itemDescriptions = {};
  extractedNumbersSubtot = {};
  numberPattern = RegularExpression["\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?"];
  
  Do[
   (*Print["positionsItemDesc dims = ",Dimensions[
   positionsItemDesc]];*)
   
   If[
    Dimensions[positionsItemDesc] =!= {0},
    pos = 
     Flatten[positionsItemDesc][[
      2]];(*Get the end positionsItemDesc of the match*)
    
    (*Extract lines of text directly below the item description \
header*)
    itemLines = StringSplit[StringDrop[invoiceText, pos], "\n"];
    Print["itemLines Dims = ", Dimensions[itemLines]];
    Print["Length[itemLines] = ", Length[itemLines]];
    Print["Min[Length[itemLines]] = ", Min[Length[itemLines]]];
    (*Ensure we handle empty lines*)
    itemIndex = 1;
    qtyIndex = 1;
    
    (*Match the lines that are under the headers and collect them*)
    Do[
     If[StringLength[itemLines[[i]]] > 0,
      Print["i = ", i];
      itemLine = StringTrim[itemLines[[i]]];
      Print["itemLine = ", itemLine];
      AppendTo[itemDescriptions, itemLine];
      ],
     {i, 1, Min[Length[itemLines]]}]
    ],
   {positionsItemDesc, allPositionsItemDesc}
   ];
  
  Do[
   (*Print["positionSubtot dims = ",Dimensions[positionSubtot]];*)
   
   If[
    Dimensions[positionSubtot] =!= {0},
    pos = 
     Flatten[positionSubtot][[
      2]];(*Get the end positionSubtot of the match*)
    
    (*Extract the text after the similar string's positionSubtot*)
    afterText = StringDrop[invoiceText, pos];
    
    (*Find the first number following the similar string*)
    number = StringCases[afterText, numberPattern, 1];
    
    (*If a number is found,add it to the list of extracted numbers*)
    If[number =!= {},
     AppendTo[extractedNumbersSubtot, number[[1]]]
     (*Print["No number found after positionSubtot: ",pos]*)
     ];
    ],
   {positionSubtot, allPositionsSubtot}
   ];
  
  (*Flatten the list to handle any nested structure and get the first \
number*)
  firstExtractedNumberSubtot = 
   If[Length[extractedNumbersSubtot] > 0, 
    Flatten[extractedNumbersSubtot][[1]], "No numbers found"];
  
  (*Add the result to the firstEntriesSubtot list*)
  AppendTo[allItemDescriptions, Flatten[itemDescriptions]];
  AppendTo[firstEntriesSubtot, firstExtractedNumberSubtot],
  {i, Length[pdfFiles]}
  ];

(*Final output:List of first extracted numbers for each file*)
Print["All item descriptions for each file: ", allItemDescriptions];
Print["First entries in extractedNumbersSubtot for each file: ", 
  firstEntriesSubtot];

In the image below which I converted to a pdf, I would like the code to extract the Item Descriptions: "Endurance Watch SKU: 24-MG01", "Fusion Backpack SKU: 24-MB02", etc and the corresponding Subtotals: "$49.00", $50.00", etc.

How do I update the code to be able to do this?
